# How to deploy single class Wildfly?

Tags: java, wildfly, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

When I've worked with Weblogic I remember we were able to put .class files into WEB-INF/class directory and restart server and a new class will be used.
Are there some similar abilities for Wildfly?

Comment: You can deploy a normal web project and add class files  to the deployment directory however you want, yes (but you don't need to restart the server, just redeploy the project).

Comment: @dan1st actually I have more complicated case, I have docker container with thirdpaty service so only one thing that is allowed for me substitute one class

Comment: And what stops you from just overwriting it (or even overwriting the whole `WAR` file) ? And if you can stop the container, why can't you change the deployment in the web dashboard of wildfly?

Comment: @dan1st for deploy war we need fork of whole project and deploy single class looks like good alternative

Comment: Why? This strongly sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). What are you **actually** trying to do? And why would require deploying a WAR fork but not deploying a class file? Anyways, you could just add the file to the `WEB-INF/classes` of the deployment directory.

Comment: @dan1st I have keycloak that deployed in docker container, and I must modify error message for some specific case. And I know place where I can do it. I cant build keycloack from source since our organisation doesn’t  wont to support own fork.

Comment: and what stops you from building a WAR from source using your modified class?

Comment: @dan1st my managers

Comment: @dan1st what about main question, do you know how to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238518/discussion-between-dan1st-and-jungle).

Comment: There are several ways to do that : deployment scanner, exploded deployments, deployment overlays. As long as the management port is accessible.

Comment: @ehsavoie I want to pack it in container and keep it there, in order to each time when container starts replaced class should used

Comment: Then you need to do it when you are building your image, it is a simple jboss cli command to execute

Comment: @ehsavoie I will be very appreciative if you put steps how to do it in the answer :)

Comment: for persistence of the change i 'm not sure, you would need to update your image. As for the command /deployment-overlay:add or /deployment=mydep:explode() and /deployment=mydep:add-content(...) cf https://docs.wildfly.org/25/wildscribe/deployment/index.html